# C language, why do we use envp[i] != 0 but not '\0';

Tags: c

I am trying to print the content of `envp` and in my `for` loop I use `envp[i] != '\0'`, but the compiler gives a warning `"Comparison between pointer and zero constant"`.

I checked someone else's solution: instead of `'\0'`, they use `envp[i] != 0`. Why this is correct? What does the number `0` stands for. I understand `envp` is an array of pointers which each element is a pointer to `char` array.

Comment: What type is `envp`? What type is `envp[i]`? What type is `'\0'`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Assuming it is the third parameter of the POSIX `main` function, `envp` has type `char **`. `'\0'` has type `int` of course. Technically, it is a valid null pointer constant, but is unusual enough as such for OP's compiler to issue a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, `envp` points to an array of string pointers. Comparing these pointers to `NULL`, or `0` is fine as these are accepted representations of the null pointer, but comparing them to `'\0'` is somewhat non-sensical: `'\0'` is a character constant representing the null byte. While its type is `int` and its value is 0 and hence could be another form for the null pointer, it is inconsistent to compare a pointer to a character value. The compiler emits an obnoxious warning for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

The constant literal `0` is "special" in C -- it can be either an int constant or a pointer constant, depending on context.  Only a literal `0` has this special behavior -- other constants such as `0U` or `'\0'` do not -- they are always integer constants so can't be comapred to (or assigned to) a pointer without a cast.

Comment: *Only a literal `0` has this special behavior -- other constants such as `0U` or `'\0'` do not*... While this is rooted ini common sense, it is not what the C Standard says: **6.3.2.3 Pointers** p3 *An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.* For example some environments define `NULL` as `0L`.